# Validation rule (exists) generate error during testing

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I have this validate rule:

```
'city' => 'required|integer|exists:cities,id'
```

It works correctly but if I try do the test, it display error

> The given data was invalid

Problem is with rule exists: exists:cities,id. Without that test return success. I'll only mention that city with this id exist. My test look like this

```
/**  @test */
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();


        $this->actingAs(factory(User::class)->create())
        ->json('POST', '/store/ad', [
            'title' => 'Hello World',
            "city" => "1",
            "phone" => "555455555",
            "mail" => "helloworld@op.pl",
            "description" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et gravida orci. Mauris rhoncus, nisi ac tristique ultricies, purus justo aliquam lorem, sit amet congue diam nulla tempus justo."
        ])
        ->assertStatus(302);
}
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Do you have a city in your test database with id = 1? Maybe you need to run `factory(City::class)->create();` first.

Comment: If you have not used DatabaseMigrations; in your test class, then maybe you had an old record leftover from the previous test which that causes the request not passing the validation. I would suggest checking if you have a clean table on every new test.